# out of office exception

Tags: exchange-2010, helpdesk

We're using trackit for our helpdesk. Our problem is, that as soon as trackit sends a mail to a user about e.g. the progress of a ticket (closed, resolved and so on) and the recipient has configured his "out of office" auto reply, trackit appends this reply to the ticket and reopens the ticket when it was already closed.

Is there a way to prevent the exchange server from sending out of office messages to a specific mail address (e.g. helpdesk@mycompany.com).
I found a way to exclude specific mail adresses on the client side, but since we have > 3000 employers this is not realy an option.
Or can I configure trackit to ignore these messages.

Comment: Exchange should be able to drop the message for you based on the sender, recipient and subject. Need to look at transport rules

Comment: Could you add a Precedence: list and Precedence: bulk to trackit emails ? They will not allow the smtp server to send a out-of-office message

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you will need to configure to resolve the issue:

1. Create an ignore rule in Track-it that ignores out of office email replies. (Only creating this rule doesn't work. It is because how Track-It deals with replies to order them in a conversation. See the link below for explanation.)
2. To configure the out of office replies so, that the original subject is NOT kept and replies are sent only once to the same address per day.

Read details here: [Track-It! Email 101: Email Conversation and "Ignore Rules"](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-26147)

Comment: Step 1. does not work. We already tried. Since the oof message contains "[[WO#1234]]" trackit ignores the rule an reopens the ticket. Step 2 is a very good point and will significantly reduce the amount of oof messages to trackit.

Comment: Why the step 1 doesn't work is explained in the link, it is because how Track-it deals with replies, and so they recommend to do the other changes that the ignore rule works.